# TensorBoard callback in model.evaluate()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

According to the official [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/tensorboard/), the TensorBoard callback can be used with `Model.evaluate`:

> When used in Model.evaluate, in addition to epoch summaries, there will be a summary that records evaluation metrics vs Model.optimizer.iterations written. The metric names will be prepended with evaluation, with Model.optimizer.iterations being the step in the visualized TensorBoard.

I would assume that passing a TensorBoard callback to `Model.evaluate` would create a folder `eval` that contains the log files. But nothing happens when I add the callback:

```
Model.evaluate(xTest, yTest, callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir="./Logs/")]
```

The TensorBoard callback works just fine in `Model.fit`.

Does anyone know how to visualize the model evaluation with TensorBoard?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try again by specifying the `evaluate` folder inside the `logs` folder to store the `model.evaluate()` metric's logs:

```
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/evaluate/")])
```

and then visualize the `model.evaluate` on `tensorboard`:

```
%tensorboard --logdir logs/evaluate/
```

Please find the working [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/f8d3f99d97a4a121fa0f9780809c64df/gist_72702174.ipynb#scrollTo=Orz8y9znoO38) for the same. Thank you.